# Whats wrong with my code? Calculation is coming out incorrect

Tags: java, calculation, converters

My objective is to take the width of a sphere, convert it into a radius, find the area in inches then feet.
then to calculate the volume in inches and then into feet.
the area works just fine however when it goes to calculate the volume it comes out in a weird form and not the correct number

my formulas and variables seem fine so i don't really know what to try next

```
System.out.println("Enter the width of the sphere: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // enables scanner
    p = sc.nextInt(); //scans user input for width
    q = 2; // var used to divide width by 2
    r = p/q; // user input divded by 2 to get radius 
    System.out.println("Division of the integers = "+r);
double pi = 3.14;
double r2 = r * r; // radius squared 
double r3 = r*r*r; // radius cubed
double a2 = 4 * pi * r2; // area formula
double volume = 4/3 * pi * r3; // volume formula for 
double v2g = 7.48; // gallons convert
System.out.println("the area of the sphere is:" + a2 );
System.out.println("the are of the sphere in feet is"+ a2 / 144);
System.out.println("the volume of the sphere in inches is" + volume);
System.out.println("the volume of the sphere in feet is" + volume / 1728);
```

This is the output that it reads after user inputs a width of 400

Enter the width of the sphere: 
400
Division of the integers = 200.0   (correct)
the area of the sphere is:502400.0 (correct)
the are of the sphere in feet is3488.8888888888887  (correct)
the volume of the sphere in inches is2.512E7    (incorrect)
the volume of the sphere in feet is14537.037037037036 (incorrect)
gallons 1943.454149336502

i expect to output of the sphere in inches to be around 33,493,333
and the sphere in feet to be around 19,383

Answer (score 4):

`4/3` equals `1`, since it's integer division. You should use `4.0 / 3` instead (or any other way to perform float-point division).

BTW, you want to use `Math.PI`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI

Comment: Thank you solved my issue. appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

As said above, 4/3 being an integer division, it does `1 * pi * r3` which messes up your calculation.

You can do `4.0/3` or `(double)4/3`

As suggested above, you can also use `Math.PI` instead of manually assigning 3.14 to `pi`, that way you can change the precision of your equation a lot more easily. Keep in mind, you probably need to round your results or PI in your equation otherwise when you display them it will give absurdly long numbers:

```
the volume of the sphere in inches is 3.3493333333333332E7
```

For this, you can use `Math.Round`:

```
System.out.println("the volume of the sphere in inches is" + Math.round(volume*1000)/1000);
```

This will display as:

```
the volume of the sphere in inches is 33493333
```